# What does the first line ("#!..") in a CGI script do?

Tags: apache, python-3.x, cgi

I am using Python in Apache on a Raspberry Pi.  The first line of the Python files has the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

What does it mean? The `/usr/bin/env` folder contains no files. My Python executable is the symbolic link `/usr/bin/python`.

The above works fine and it runs Python 2.7, the one pointed to by `/usr/bin/python`. If I want to use Python 3 can do it by just changing this line to some appropriate values?

Comment: It's called the shebang line, and `/usr/bin/env` should be an executable file.

Comment: Do you have a `python3` binary, or something similarly named?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` is a program, not a folder: it finds and launches `python` (or whatever was supplied as an argument). This allows python (or whatever) to be installed in different locations which may differ between systems while maintaining a portable script. There should be a `python3` available if Python 3 is installed.

Comment: @user2864740 My mistake. Yes, `/usr/bin/env` is some file and not a folder. If I want to use Python 3, can I change it to `/usr/bin/python3.4` or `/usr/bin/env python3`?  On my Pi, `/usr/bin/env/python3` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python3.4`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python3` - use Python 3. `/usr/bin/env python` - use the "default" Python, probably still Python 2 where such is installed.

Comment: Thanks.  The duplicate reference actually explains everything.